# Center first item if recyclerview's list size is odd(GridLayoutManager)

Tags: android

Im trying to set the first item to center horizontally if the list size is odd,

```
 GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(recyclerViewHolder.recyclerView.getContext(), 2);
                    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                        @Override
                        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                            if (position == 0&&questionsAndAnswersChatModel.get(position).getAnswers().size()%2!=0) {
                                return 2; 
                            }
                            return 1;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't center the first item

Comment: what are you passing to the adapter? questionsAndAnswersChatModel or its answer?

Comment: Does it really matter what am i passing?

Comment: yes if you are passing the  questionsAndAnswersChatModel to the adapter to calculate if the adapter has odd childer you need to do something like this.  `questionsAndAnswersChatModel.size()%2 !=0` instead of what you are doing right now

Answer (score 0):

The above code will insert only one item in first row but to center it, add `layout_gravity = center` parameter to your `RecyclerView`

```
<RecyclerView
...
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
.../>
```